# I was trying to run kubebuilder and this error pops up everytime I try to Install Instances of Custom Resources

Tags: docker, go, kubebuilder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YlPN.png)
This is the error that comes.

I cannot find a way out.
I am running linux command line on windows 10. And trying to run kubebuilder there. Is me running the linux shell in windows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using NFS for storage in your Kubernetes cluster, ensure that the NFS server and related configurations are set up correctly. Verify the NFS server's availability and make sure the mount points are properly configured.
- The mountinfo file contains information about mounted filesystems and is used by Kubernetes to determine NFS usage. Check the contents of the mountinfo file, typically located at /proc/self/mountinfo, to ensure its format is correct. If you have made any modifications to this file, revert them to their original state.
- Make sure that the user running the command has the necessary permissions to access and read the files. You can check the permissions using the ls -l command:
  `ls -l /config/samples/`.